# Using shell variable in awk

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, awk, sh

I am new to `awk` and need some help

this works

```
awk '{
for(i =0;i<10;i++){
if ($27 == 'addr1') {
    print >"temp.csv"
     }
    }
}' /tmp/input.csv
```

i tried below and is not working, how to pass count value from outside to awk command

```
count=10
echo $count
awk '{
for(i =0;i<count;i++){
if ($27 == 'addr1') {
    print >"temp.csv"
     }
    }
}' /tmp/input.csv
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we use shell variables in awk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786777/can-we-use-shell-variables-in-awk)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to print a line 10 times to a new file if field number 27 is equal to `"addr1"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-v` option to set a variable inside `awk`:

```
awk -v count="$count" '...'
```

"Filename" arguments of the form `X=Y` are also interpreted as variable assignments. The following should work:

```
awk '...' count="$count" /tmp/input.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want compare against a string inside awk, you need double quotes around the string. Like

```
awk -v count=$count '
$27=="addr1" {
  for(i=0;i<count;i++)
     print > "temp.csv" 
}' /tmp/input.csv
```

(Note that for instance `'if ($27 == 'addr1')'` will expand to `'if ($27 == addr1)'`, that is: `addr1` without double quotes)

If you instead want compare against the shell variable `$addr1` inside awk, you can do

```
awk -v count=$count -vaddr1="$addr1" '
$27==addr1 {
  for(i=0;i<count;i++)
     print > "temp.csv" 
}' /tmp/input.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the `-v` argument to awk to pass in values from the outside as awk variables.

```
count=2
echo $count
awk -vcount=$count '{
for(i =0;i<count;i++){
if ($27 == 'addr1') {
    print >"temp.csv"
     }
    }
}' /tmp/input.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simply  trick : break the `awk` code enclosure (single quotes)  to put what you want inside, a piece of embedded code.

```
> a=10                                                                                                          
> awk 'BEGIN{for (i=0;i<='${a}';i++){printf("%d ", i)}}'
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The good: Simple and handy.

The bad: It makes your program less readable .