# utilizing a variable in awk then enter output into another variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /home/user/list
read -p "enter a number: " LISTNUMBER
USERNAME=$(awk '$LISTNUMBER {
  match($0, $LISTNUMBER); print substr($0, RLENGTH + 2); }' /home/user/list)

echo "you chose $USERNAME."
```

This script will use awk to search another file that has a list of numbers and usernames:
1 bob
2 fred 
etc...
I only want the username not the corresponding number which is why I tried using: `print substr($0, RLENGTH + 2)`

Unfortunately, the output of the awk won't attach to $USERNAME.

I have attempted to `grep` for this but could not achieve the answer. I then read about `awk` and got here, but am stuck again. Utilizing `grep` or `awk` is all the same for me.

Comment: use awk -v variable... : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786777/can-we-use-shell-variables-in-awk

Comment: my apologies if this is a re-ask. thanks for the link.

Comment: No thing wrong with asking same question again..  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Single*-quoted strings in POSIX-like shells are invariably *literals* - no interpolation of their contents is performed. Therefore, `$LISTNUMBER` in your code will *not* expand to its value.

To pass shell variables to Awk, use `-v {awkVarName}="${shellVarName}"`.

Also, Awk performs automatic splitting of input lines into fields of by runs of whitespace (by default); `$1` represents the 1st field, `$2` the 2nd, ...

If we apply both insights to your scenario, we get:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "enter a number: " LISTNUMBER
USERNAME=$(awk -v LISTNUMBER="$LISTNUMBER" '
  $1 == LISTNUMBER { print $2 }' /home/user/list)

echo "you chose $USERNAME."
```