# Awk command in Tcl foreach loop

Tags: loops, awk, tcl

I need to pass a variable value to awk command used in tickle.
Goal : i want to extract fisrt field of file clk_gate_names one by one in loop.So this is small example shown the same concept have benn used in one script.

one testcase below:

```
set a 0
incr a
foreach i {0.. 11} { # i variable is used for another thing
set test [exec awk {NR==${a}{print $1}} clk_gate_names]
}
```

Getting below error:
awk: NR==${a}{print $1}
awk:      ^ syntax error

Please throw some light here. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try `exec awk -v a=${a} 'NR==a{print $1}' clk_gate_names`

Comment: Now i am getting below error % exec awk -v a="$a" 'NR==a{print $1}' clk_gate_name can't read "1": no such variable

Comment: No it didnt work. What i tried is exec awk -v a=${a} {NR==a{print $1}} clk_gate_names is having no syntax error but not printing anuthing at same time. Can we on this think what is wrong here. :)

Comment: `exec awk -v a=${a} {NR==a{print $1}}` try this

Comment: % exec awk -v a=${a} 'NR==a{print \$1}' clk_gate_names
awk: 'NR==a{print
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: check 
http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.tcl/fmm.html

Comment: This is working exec awk -v a=${a} "NR==a{print \$1}" clk_gate_names
eco_net_2_16_G3B171I56

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're wanting to mix variables from Tcl and variables from Awk. That's a bit complicated, as they are *necessarily* separate processes.

One option is to use Tcl's `format` command to build the Awk script-let.

```
set a 0
incr a
foreach i {0.. 11} { # i variable is used for another thing
    set awkcode [format {NR==%d {print $1}} $a]
    set test [exec awk $awkcode clk_gate_names]
}
```

However, a better approach is to pass the variable in by the `-v` option. That has the advantage of being not easily confused by any weird quoting going on, and Tcl doesn't break words unexpectedly (except, in `exec`, when it looks like a file/pipe redirection; that's a wart).

```
set a 0
incr a
foreach i {0.. 11} { # i variable is used for another thing
    set test [exec awk -v a=$a {NR==a {print $1}} clk_gate_names]
}
```

The third way is to [use an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15787182/301832). That has the advantage of not being susceptible to the problems with redirections (so you can pass in values containing `>` for example).

```
set a 0
incr a
foreach i {0.. 11} { # i variable is used for another thing
    set env(A_FROM_TCL) $a
    set test [exec awk {NR==$ENVIRON["A_FROM_TCL"] {print $1}} clk_gate_names]
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Remember with awk and Tcl, don't use single quotes. Tcl doesn't use the same syntax as bash. Put the script in braces always or you'll get very confused.
2. I assume you know about the syntax of `foreach`? For the purposes of our discussion here it's not important, but you'd probably be having problems from it if the code you posted is *exactly* what you are using…

Answer (score 0):

try below logic -

```
awk -v a=1 'NR==a {print $1}' f
```

As per your code -

```
set a 0
incr a
foreach i {0.. 11} { # i variable is used for another thing
set test [exec awk -v a="$a" 'NR==a {print $1}' clk_gate_names]
}
```

let me know if it satisfy your req. and share the output(desired output/error)

Comment: Now i am getting below error                                                                      % exec awk -v a="$a" 'NR==a{print $1}' clk_gate_name can't read "1": no such variable

Comment: Can you try below cmd, just for testing if variable is fetching value properly or not as i don't have any idea about what you are trying to achive in code - 

`awk -v a=1 'NR==a {print $1}'` clk_gate_names (in your code)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v a=${a} "NR==a{print \$1}" filename
```

Check :

http://phaseit.net/claird/comp.lang.tcl/fmm.html

> > AWK: who | awk '{ print $1 }' works from the command line, but my Tcl interpreter rejects exec who | awk '{ print $1 }' I often hear
> >     that from people who haven't yet learned to ask tclsh to interpret
> >     exec who | awk {{ print $1 }} Notice that the '-s aren't "about" awk;
> >     they're just conventional quoting in the shells from which one most
> >     often accesses awk. exec doesn't use the shells. {} perform an
> >     analogous function of quoting for Tcl. More examples appear in this
> >     Google thread. Alexandre Ferrieux gives a correct and concise
> >     explanation in another thread. The problem at hand for him happened to
> >     do with sed, but that's essentially inconsequential; the command-line
> >     syntaxes of awk and sed exhibit identical symptoms. Briefly, as the
> >     error messages which arise themselves say, the single quotes (') are
> >     the problem. These are shell markup for strings which shall not be
> >     substituted. /bin/sh and others remove this markup before calling awk.
>
> In Tcl, in contrast, braces {} serve the same purpose. Braces have the
>   advantage that they can be nested. One conclusion: brace the braces
>   that awk expects: awk -F " " {{print $1}}. Note that, in this last, it
>   is not necessary to escape the dollar-sign, because the outer brace
>   protect it, too.
>
> Much the same has been written several times by Richard Suchenwirth,
>   Mark Janssen, Kevin Kenny, and others; it's unlikely any particular
>   expression was invented in isolation.