# Syntax error in awk

Tags: bash, awk, cat

I am writing a small programme whose functionality is like following. It uses a file named hist1.dat and the first step is like this

```
awk '{if(NR>1) s+=$2*($1-x); x=$1}END{print s}' hist1.dat >int1.txt
```

The hist1.dat is like following

```
0.259990113102 4
0.261752339307 10
0.263514565512 15
0.265276791717 35
0.267039017922 58
0.268801244127 84
0.270563470333 147
0.272325696537 217
0.274087922742 316
0.275850148947 410
0.277612375152 583
0.279374601357 750
0.281136827562 881
0.282899053767 1004
0.284661279972 1241
```

The `int1.txt` contains a value `79.9504` . The second step uses this value and process it further like following

```
awk '{if(NR>1) s+=$2*($1-x); print $1,s/c1; x=$1}' c1="$(cat int1.txt)" hist1.dat >cutoff1_org.txt
```

The `cutoff1_org.txt` looks like following

```
0.321668030277 0.832661
0.323430256483 0.851265
0.325192482688 0.867267
0.326954708893 0.882167
0.328716935097 0.895634
0.330479161302 0.906677
0.332241387507 0.917587
0.334003613712 0.927175
0.335765839917 0.935287
0.337528066122 0.9432
0.339290292327 0.94968
0.341052518532 0.955675
0.342814744737 0.961097
0.344576970942 0.96555
0.346339197147 0.969231
```

The next script uses the cutoff1_org.txt file and tries to find a value in column 1 if the corresponding value in column 2 is close to 0.95. This works well too

```
awk -v c=2 -v t=0.95 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$1}END{print v}' cutoff1_org.txt >final_cutoff1.txt
```

The next two scripts will just use values from final_cutoff1.txt. Something like following

```
awk '{ if ($1 >= cutoff1) print $1 }' cutoff1="$(cat final_cutoff1.txt)" hist1.dat >hist_oc1.dat                                                                                                         
awk '{ if ($1 <= cutoff1) print $1 }' cutoff1="$(cat final_cutoff1.txt)" hist1.dat >hist_uc1.dat
```

Now I want to put inside a loop like following

```
for i in {1..22}; do                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    awk '{if(NR>1) s+=$2*($1-x); x=$1}END{print s}' hist${i}.dat >int${i}.txt                                                                                                                                               
    awk '{if(NR>1) s+=$2*($1-x); print $1,s/c${i}; x=$1}' c${i}="$(cat int${i}.txt)" hist${i}.dat >cutoff${i}_org.txt                                                                                                       
    awk -v c=2 -v t=0.95 'NR==1{d=$c-t;d=d<0?-d:d;v=$c;next}{m=$c-t;m=m<0?-m:m}m<d{d=m;v=$1}END{print v}' cutoff${i}_org.txt >final_cutoff${i}.txt                                                                          
    awk '{ if ($1 >= cutoff${i}) print $1 }' cutoff${i}="$(cat final_cutoff${i}.txt)" hist${i}.dat >hist_oc${i}.dat                                                                                                         
    awk '{ if ($1 <= cutoff${i}) print $1 }' cutoff${i}="$(cat final_cutoff${i}.txt)" hist${i}.dat >hist_uc${i}.dat                                                                                                         
    cat hist_oc${i}.dat |stdev >stat_oc${i}.txt                                                                                                                                                                             
    cat hist_uc${i}.dat |stdev >stat_uc${i}.txt                                                                                                                                                                             
done
```

However I got an error like following

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if(NR>1) s+=$2*($1-x); print $1,s/c${i}; x=$1}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {if(NR>1) s+=$2*($1-x); print $1,s/c${i}; x=$1}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                               ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: { if ($1 >= cutoff${i}) print $1 }
awk: cmd. line:1:                    ^ syntax error
```

I think I have brain fade now. Seems like very easy error to fix. Can anyone please point out and help with it. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15787068/8344060

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use shell variables in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786777/can-we-use-shell-variables-in-awk)

Comment: awk '{if(NR>1) s+=$2*($1-x); print $1,s/c${i}; x=$1}' -v c${i}="$(cat int${i}.txt)" hist${i}.dat >cutoff${i}_org.txt   something like that?

Comment: the problem is your `${i}` in your Awk. It is a shell variable and unknown to Awk. the link explains how to do it

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it -v c${i}="$(cat int${i}.txt)" this is what I add in awk but still the problem exists

Comment: `awk '{if(NR>1) s+=$2*($1-x); print $1,s/c; x=$1}' c="$(cat int${i}.txt)" hist${i}.dat >cutoff${i}_org.txt`

Comment: Clean up your question to get rid of all the irrelevant and duplicate information and just show us 1 awk script with 1 **small** input file and the assocatied expected output that demonstrate your problem, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Okay great thanks a lot I solved it.

Comment: You're really missing the point of using awk and have extremely inefficient and redundant code, even if so far it does produce the output you expect. As a very basic example, 2 passes of the input like `awk '{ if ($1 >= cutoff1) { print $1 }' in > out1` and `awk '{ if ($1 <= cutoff1) { print $1 }' in > out2` should be just 1 pass of the input: `awk '{ if ($1 == cutoff1) { print $1 > "out1"; print $1 > "out2" } else { print $1 > ($1 > cutoff1 ? "out1" : "out2"}' in`. Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Best I can tell without knowing more about your input, expected output, and requirements your shell loop containing 5 calls to awk should just be a single small awk script. Post a new question if you'd like help doing whatever you're doing the right way.