# awk with $var as search pattern

Tags: variables, search, awk

I am facing a problem where I want awk to search for a pattern that comes from a bash variable...
Now it looks like:

```
for i in ${CLASS_LIST[*]}; do
cat log.txt | awk -F ":" '$1 ~ /$i/ {print substr($0, index($0,$2))}'
done
```

But awk has no output here.
If I do it like:

```
cat log.txt | awk -F ":" '$1 ~ /LABEL/ {print substr($0, index($0,$2))}
```

it works well... what is wrong in the first example?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.
regards,
Joerg

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Take a look at awk's option `-v`. See: [Can we use shell variables in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15786777/3776858)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip, Cyrus. I've already tried the "-v" option with the same result.
But I found my mistake...

when give a variable as search pattern, don't pack it in to "/"...
This is working for me:

```
for i in ${CLASS_LIST[*]}; do
cat log.txt | awk -v var="$i" -F ":" '$1 ~ var {print substr($0, index($0,$2))}'
done
```

Regards,
Joerg